Difference between لحم and عضلة
In Quran it is mentioned that the bones are covered with muscles in early stage.But in Quran  is it flesh(لحم) not muscle(عضلة).Is flesh  and muscle in Arabic same or different?Is flesh comprehensive in this case?

In the Quran, Surah Al-Mu’minun (23:14) mentions that bones are covered with flesh (لحم), not muscles (عضلة):

"Then We made the sperm into a clot of congealed blood, then We made the clot into a lump, then We made the lump into bones, and We clothed the bones with flesh (لحم).".  Surah Al-Mu’minun (23:14)

In Arabic, لحم (lahm) generally refers to flesh, which can include muscle, but it is a broader term that encompasses all soft tissue covering the bones, not just muscle tissue.
عضلة (adalah) specifically refers to muscle tissue, which is distinct from flesh, as muscles are a subset of flesh.
So, flesh (لحم) in this case is comprehensive and can include muscles, but it’s not limited to them.
The Quran uses لحم to describe the covering over the bones, which can be understood as including both muscle and other soft tissues.
